# SQL: storing coded rows as separate columns for a given ID

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that contains geocoded data for a set of addresses. The issue is that latitude and longitude are stored in the same column, but are differentiated by a code (0 or 1) in another column in the same table. Each address is marked with an unique id that appears twice in the column (1 for lat, 1 for long).

I would like to show lat and long on the same row as separate columns along with the corresponding ID.

Comment: show some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: It's hard to image without sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    select unique_id, 
         max(case when code = 0 then geocoded_column end) as lat, 
         max(case when code = 1 then geocoded_column end) as long
    from geocoded_table
    group by unique_id
```

Comment: thanks! I had seen a similar suggestion in another thread but I couldn't get it to work. Started over and this worked so I must have had an issue somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
with ttt as (
            select 111 ID, '54.65548' coords, 1 def from dual
            union all
            select 111 ID, '-34.8456' coords, 0 def from dual
            )
select t1.ID, t1.coords, t2.coords
from ttt t1
    join ttt t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
                   and t1.def <> t2.def 
                   and t1.def = 1 -- or t1.def = 0 if you want change order of coords
```